# Create a shader for earth night and day also create clickable sprites

Tags: click, three.js, shader

My question is in multiple parts please answer the part that you can I am aware each presents its own unique challenges.

First: I need to create a shader that mixes between earth in the day and earth at night (night lights in various cities). I've tried a technique that I saw on a previously answered question about this very topic but it didn't work out for me. The relevant code follows:

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform sampler2D dayTexture;
    uniform sampler2D nightTexture;

    uniform vec3 sunDirection;

    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vNormal;

    void main( void ) {
        vec3 dayColor = texture2D( dayTexture, vUv ).rgb;
        vec3 nightColor = texture2D( nightTexture, vUv ).rgb;

        // compute cosine sun to normal so -1 is away from sun and +1 is toward sun.
        float cosineAngleSunToNormal = dot(normalize(vNormal), sunDirection);

        // sharpen the edge beween the transition
        cosineAngleSunToNormal = clamp( cosineAngleSunToNormal * 10.0, -1.0, 1.0);

        // convert to 0 to 1 for mixing
        float mixAmount = cosineAngleSunToNormal * 0.5 + 0.5;

        // Select day or night texture based on mix.
        vec3 color = mix( nightColor, dayColor, mixAmount );

        gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );
        //gl_FragColor = vec4( mixAmount, mixAmount, mixAmount, 1.0 );
    }
</script>
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">


        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vNormal;

        void main()
        {
            vUv = uv;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }


</script>

<script>


uniforms = {
    sunDirection: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0) },
    dayTexture: { type: "t", value: 0, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/Color_Map.jpg" ) },
    nightTexture: { type: "t", value: 1, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/Night_Lights.jpg" ) }
};

uniforms.dayTexture.texture.wrapS = uniforms.dayTexture.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;
uniforms.nightTexture.texture.wrapS = uniforms.nightTexture.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;





material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
    });

var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

webglEl.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

render();

function render() {
    controls.update();
    lexington_line.rotation.y += 0.0005;  //0.0005
    florida_line.rotation.y += 0.0005; // 0.0005
    sphere.rotation.y += 0.0005; //0.0005
    clouds.rotation.y += 0.0007; //0.0007       
    var t = Date.now() * 0.001;
    uniforms.sunDirection.value.x = Math.sin(t);
    uniforms.sunDirection.value.y = Math.cos(t);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function createSphere(radius, segments, material) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/Color_Map.jpg'),
            bumpMap:     THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
            bumpScale:   0.005,
            specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/water_4k.png'),
            specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')                        
        })
    );
}

</script>
```

My second question I need to create a spirit that you can click and it it turns the camera so it sees pictures (not implemented) I have the code so it clicks but when I look at the console it doesn't seem to work properly. The nearest click is only correct when the surface faces you exactly but if you try and click it at an angle or some place not right above it it doesn't give you the correct click (intersect[0]). The relevant code as follows:

```
//Normal Lines. 


//Not sure if this is needed, Further testing required.
//document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


//Lexington KY Location: Normal Line.
var lex_normal = new THREE.Geometry();

var vertex = new THREE.Vector3( 0.1, 1.0, 1.3 );
vertex.normalize();
vertex.multiplyScalar( 0.5 );
lex_normal.vertices.push( vertex );
var vertex2 = vertex.clone();
vertex2.multiplyScalar( 2 );
lex_normal.vertices.push( vertex2 );
var lexington_line = new THREE.Line( lex_normal, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity:12 } ) );
lexington_line.rotation.y = rotation;
scene.add( lexington_line );
lexington_line.onClick = function(){
    console.log('Target Normal: Lexington, KY USA');

    }

//Miami FL:: TEST!  
var mia_normal = new THREE.Geometry();

var vertex = new THREE.Vector3( 0.26, 1.0, 1.72 );
vertex.normalize();
vertex.multiplyScalar( 0.3 );
mia_normal.vertices.push( vertex );
var vertex2 = vertex.clone();
vertex2.multiplyScalar( 2 );
mia_normal.vertices.push( vertex2 );
var florida_line = new THREE.Line( mia_normal, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, opacity:12 } ) );
florida_line.rotation.y = rotation;
scene.add( florida_line );
florida_line.rotation.y = rotation;
florida_line.onClick = function(){
    console.log('Target Normal: Miami, FL USA');
}

// Projector to generate the 3D coordinates from the click
var projector = new THREE.Projector();

// push all the clickable objects into this array
var clickableObjects = [];    
clickableObjects.push(lexington_line,florida_line);

// Bind the mousedown handler
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // transforms the 2D click coordinates into a THREE.Vector3 for 3D coordinates
  var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - (     event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2+1, 0.2 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

  // casts a ray from the camera position directly to the calculated vector
  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position     ).normalize() );


  // iterates through the clickable objects and checks if they intersect with the ray
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( clickableObjects );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    // The intersects array contains all the elements,
    // that intersect with the casted ray. intersects[0] is the nearest object.
    intersects[0].object.onClick();
  }


}

}());
```

If the question isn't clear please say so, I will try and rephrase if I have to.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The result I get in the first question is nothing. I passed the material into the function but no matter where I place the material it doesn't seem to have the desired effect. For instance if I pass it in like this :

```
function createSphere(radius, segments, material) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/Color_Map.jpg'),
            bumpMap:     THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
            bumpScale:   0.005,
            specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/water_4k.png'),
            specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')                        
        }), material
    );
}
```

it changes the planet color entirely 
or like this:

```
function createSphere(radius, segments, material) {
    return new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments), material,
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/Color_Map.jpg'),
            bumpMap:     THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/elev_bump_4k.jpg'),
            bumpScale:   0.005,
            specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/water_4k.png'),
            specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')                        
        })
    );
}
```

It again changes the color but differently than above. I can't get it to just show the night lights when it's night time (light not on an area).

I fixed the 0.2 to 0.5 in the recast but it didn't seem to resolve much. This issue persists that unless you are right on top of the line then it doesn't click properly.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have different questions, please open different threads.

2) What is the result you get in Querstion 1 ? Just saying it doesn't work is not much to go on.

3) In the raycast there is 0.2 where it should be 0.5 .

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - (     event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2+1, 0.2 );

I think this should be:

var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - (     event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2+1, 0.5 );